# Home state is not getting set when using Angular ui-router with Laravel 5 app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, laravel-5

I have a project with laravel 5 as backend and angularjs 1.3 as front-end.

Laravel5 setup:

```
//routes.php
//Routes for api to get json 
Route::group('prefix'=>'api', function(){
    Route::controllers([
        'subjects' => 'SubjectsController', 
        'pages' => 'PagesController',
        'articles' =>'ArticlesController'
   ]);
// route for angular
Route::get('/dash', 'DashController@index);

// handler.php
// for catch all routing
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response()->view('ajs-dash.index')->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**On Angular side**

```
//dash.js
angular.module('dash', [
'dash.content', 'dash.content.controller', 'dash.app.controller',
'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.tinymce'])
.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    default     : '*',
    super       : 'super',
    admin       : 'admin',
    manager     : 'manager',
    guest       : 'guest'
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next){
        var authorizedRoles=[],
            authorized = false,
            loggedIn=false;
        if(next.authorizedRoles){
            authorizedRoles = next.authorizedRoles;
            authorized = (authorizedRoles.indexOf($rootScope.userRole) !== -1);
            loggedIn = $rootScope.loggedIn;
        }
        //console.log('next = '); console.log(next);
        //console.log('authorizedRoles = '); console.log(authorizedRoles);
        console.log('$rootScope.userRole= '); console.log($rootScope.userRole);
        console.log('$rootScope.loggedIn= '); console.log($rootScope.loggedIn);
        if(!loggedIn && !authorized){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'USER_ROLES',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES){
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('dash', {
                abstract:false,
                url:'/',
                templateUrl:'/admin/views/dash.html',
                authorizedRoles:[USER_ROLES.admin, USER_ROLES.super]
            });
    }]);
```

and rest of the states are defined in content.js i.e. the dash.content module.
The dash.php at \dash is where I am bootstraping the angular app 'dash' by including data-ng-app="dash"on the `<html>`tag.

When I browse to `\dash` , the view isgetting loaded and from there I am even able to navigate the child states properly. 
But the problem is that when on `\dash` , the home state of dash is not getting set. If I provide a button in dash.php with ui-sref="dash" and click on it then the state is getting set.  But it is not getting set by navigating to the url.
Another problem is that whenever within any state, either dash or any child state, if I do a page refresh it looses all the states.
I am using

```
    $state = {{$state.current.name}}
    $stateParams = {{$stateParams}}
    $state full url = {{$state.$current.url.source}}
```

as given in the ui-router home example to keep track of state , stateParams and url.
So when I navigate to \dash , all three are empty
when I click on button with ui-sref="dash" - the $state = dash is set
and from there on for all child states the url as well as stateParams are also getting set. But on page refresh again it goes back to \dash and $state=empty.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: use postman( chrome extension ) for debugging your server side.

Comment: I am not getting any errors for any calls to the apis or the child sates. Even postman doesn't show any errors. Although I am not proficient with postman.  The problem that I am facing is that when navigating to the url where angularjs is getting bootstraped, the home state is not getting set. The state gets set on all child states as well as the main state when navigated through menu links.